# Make certain nested properties required in a typescript type

Tags: typescript

I am looking to make specific nested properties required in a typescript type. Like what `PartialExcept` does except nested as well.

```js
export type PartialExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, K>> &
  Partial<T>;
```

So instead of adding these unions, I can specify everything in the type helper.

```js
type Game = {
  home: PartialExcept<
    Team,
    'name' | 'description'
  > & {
    goals: Required<Goal>[];
    metadata: PartialExcept<
      Metadata,
      'time' | 'period'
    >;
  };
};
```

Where the types are

```js
type Team = {
  name?: string
  description?: string
  goals?: Goal[]
  metadata?: Metadata
}

type Metadata = {
{
  time?: string
  period?: number
  shots?: number
}

type Goal = {
  scorer?: string
  number?: string
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the example to show how you'd like to write `type Game = PartialNestedExceptHelper<???>`?  What type arguments do you want to pass it? How do you want to specify the nested keys?  And what type specifically should it be equivalent to (could you expand it out as a plain object type instead of writing it in terms of `PartialExcept` and unions?  It would be a lot easier to work with.)

Answer (score 0):

Someone actually solved it, not quite the syntax I was looking for but it works

```js
type DeepPartialExcept<T extends object, K extends NestedKeyOf<T>> = UnionToIntersection<PartialExceptUnion<T, K> | DeepPartial<T>>

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends U ? (arg: U) => void : never) extends ((arg: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type PartialExceptUnion<T, K extends string> =
  K extends `${infer KFirst extends Extract<keyof T, string>}.${infer KRest extends string}`
    ? { [Key in KFirst]: Key extends keyof T ? PartialExceptUnion<T[Key], KRest> : never }
    : K extends keyof T ? { [Key in K]: NonNullable<T[Key]> } : never;

type DeepPartial<T> = T extends object ? {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
} : T;

type NestedKeyOf<T extends object> = 
    {[P in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[P] extends object 
        ? `${P}` | `${P}.${NestedKeyOf<T[P]>}`
        : `${P}`
        }[keyof T & (string | number)];

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: {
    city: string;
    street: string;
    zip: number;
    country: {
        code: string
        name: string
    }
  };
}

const TestCase_1: DeepPartialExcept<Person, 'address.street' | 'age' | 'address.country.code'> = {
    age: 99,
    address: {
        street: 'Quebec',
        country: {
            // @ts-expect-error
            code: undefined
        }
    },
    name: undefined
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhZBDA1gUwM6VcgNsgxgF2QBNIAzAS2yPQCdkBHAV3LqIBpJ4A7E-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-xGhpRk0rBwbq0zIgu6v5afjRbVptbFPbehLZaH1Yy7ib21kW0YWCw8GCOEHVYbF3jc95U4A3FqkZCJN3Ybo8cvhRT5ksCCvZ+WepAayXXQGypRkHyfLBBx6M9bwvRldFvREdR2ERiCrY5JgXOZFmWV9ZzdP8AIyIDIAAMiJPMLAqLhGC0UJBS3XQ-wbLDxBw79Z2LYsaVdN0egLCpeP45M3RQvYDgwpjoNOAtOK4xkhNkrjlMgeNyxI8jCUo6jaPopkG0Q6w3lIeBRl1AVUFkUsCTkRpGUo29i3gCxkB5XSBUczgiCIYRUEZN1Z1wcg2nskM4084srW6fBQutCwIsgAAvcgJDcuiPMCsRUhDOx-Lk4sSiIVyMDCm18sgWziso2cZ2LeNYIREouH9XRdgAYXgTAAH0AEYwO6R9oSGPspG+CzZA4Ap4G83zEyi5B8FqQpnLKCoppmtBUETEpspoOxtrEIqClfALlJWxkAE4LrYWdpp8za8pUrj5piwoAEVGGQUJcAKG6noKrLXj2x7-uU4BgFUfBUAMPJHAIGGaBoMxyuUwritSIqKF5Ihytqrj4z+rjKsZDHkCx4hwBnIA